# Php screen scraping using php simple dom parser

Tags: php, screen-scraping, html-parsing, web-scraping, simpledom

I am using simple html dom parser to scrape a website ... How can i skip a particular class while in a loop

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_find_attr you can use:

```
->find("div[class!=skip_me]")
```

Or use the DOM methods and check with `->getAttribute("class")` against a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // DOM can load HTML soup. But, HTML soup can throw warnings, suppress
  // them.
  $htmlDom = new DOMDocument();
  @$htmlDom->loadHTML($html);
  if ($htmlDom) {
    // It's much easier to work with simplexml than DOM, luckily enough
    // we can just simply import our DOM tree.
    $elements = simplexml_import_dom($htmlDom);
```

This is a quote (almost) from Drupal 7 SimpleTest. After this, it's a lot easier work with the document, the class can be reach as $element['class']

Comment: The correct way to suppress parsing errors is to use `libxml_use_internal_errors()` and then clear them with `libxml_clear_errors()`. If you use the Error Suppression Operator it will suppress any error, not just the parsing errors.